# Aurelia Possible Memory Leak

Tags: aurelia

I have a table template that is leaking I have pinpointed the code causing the issue to a single line.

```
              <tbody>
                 <tr repeat.for="row of workListData.rows" click.delegate='resultItemClick($event, row)'>                  
                    <td repeat.for="col of workListData.columns"> 
                       <template if.bind='col.name === "isChecked"'>
                          ${col.label}
                       </template>
                       <template if.bind='col.name !== "isChecked"'>              
                          **${row.Properties[col.name]}**
                       </template>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
```

**${row.Properties[col.name]}**
This is the line of code causing the issue this line takes the current row and uses the column name to access the value of the column

Comment: Try this and see if it makes any difference: `${ col.name === 'isChecked' ? col.label : row.Properties[col.name]}`. Remove both templates

Comment: Ok will need to update again thought commenting out that line was stopping the leak but maybe its something else sure its in that block of code somewhere though

Comment: How exactly is it "leaking?"

Comment: Sorry guys going to have to do more investigation thought it was in that code block but not sure now. Its definiately in that template somewhere. When I change routes the old template is being held in memory so every time I navigate I get another version of that template held in memory. If I remove all the html from that template issue goes away. I am seeing alot of detached doc fragments before then is this normal in aurelia

Comment: Think I have found the issue now it seems aurelia leaks when you have nested repeat.for.                     <tr repeat.for="row of workListData.rows" click.delegate='resultItemClick($event, row)'>                  
                        <td repeat.for="col of workListData.columns"> 

                        </td>
                     </tr>

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxcVT.jpg)Ok it seems aurelia is leaking when I have nested repeat.for

```
                 Leaks
                 <tr repeat.for="row of workListData.rows" click.delegate='resultItemClick($event, row)'>                  
                    <td repeat.for="col of workListData.columns"> 

                    </td>
                 </tr>

                 Does not leak
                 <tr repeat.for="row of workListData.rows" click.delegate='resultItemClick($event, row)'>                  

                 </tr>
```

Its definitely coming from nested repeat problem is if I simplify the code IE remove web services etc its work as expected

One of my colleagues has noticed something interesting commenting out a different template controller also stops the leak seems its not fussy which controller gets commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally located the leak it seems I had a couple however one thing for sure is aurelia seems to have a very bad tendency to leak if you do this in a template

${row.Properties[key]}

Not sure if that is supported though

I now instead pass the object and key to a function and return the value which solves the issue